# Copy last word from error and input into next command

Tags: linux, redirect, gnupg

Kind of vague title but basically what I need to do is copy the public key from this error message:

> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net hardy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EED4D034D81367B9

And use it as a value in the remainder of the script to fix the error moving forward.  I've looked up how to do this with Grep, awk, sed and a few other tools but they all involve reading input from a file, not reading in-line from standard output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to get the `EED4D034D81367B9` word from the string? Is it present in a file (or) output of a certain command? And which shell are you using? Do you have `bash` installed?

Comment: That string is the output as a result of issuing the "sudo apt-get update" command on an old (Ubuntu 8.04) VM.  And yes, I have bash installed -- I am attempting to handle all of this as part of my bash script so it is seamless to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `bash` tools with `xargs` to achieve this. Assuming  you receive the error string from a command, you can pipe it to a `regEx` in `bash` using the `tilde (=~)` operator.

```
.*\ ([[:alnum:]]+)$
```

i.e. doing a plain `echo` of the string with this `regEx` you get the required key value. Running the below command on the command line

```
$ echo "W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net hardy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EED4D034D81367B9" | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ .*\ ([[:alnum:]]+)$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
EED4D034D81367B9
```

i.e of form

```
$ <command-returning-string> | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ .*\ ([[:alnum:]]+)$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
```

Now as you said, you want to pass this key to another command in pipe-line. Now `xargs` comes to the rescue. With the `-I{}` flag in `xargs`, the `{}` becomes a placeholder for the key returned from the previous command, i.e. the key is now present in `{}` and can be passed as an argument/input to your next command as

```
$ <command-returning-string> | <command-returning-key> | xargs -I{} <your-next-command> {}
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try this out and post the results!!  Essentially, what I have to do with that string "EED4D034D81367B9" is to pipe it into the command 

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key string here> 

to resolve the error of not being able to update the respository.  Unless someone else knows of a better solution!!

Comment: @J.Doe: Your final command should be something like `| xargs -I{} sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys {}`

Comment: @J.Doe: Do not forget to mark the answer resolved ( a small tick on the left of my answer) once you get it working.